# How to reload a picker view?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6, uipickerview

```
@IBAction func nextTurn(sender: AnyObject) {
    if numberOfTurn < (playersForPicker.count-1) {
    numberOfTurn++
    }else{
        numberOfTurn = 0
    }
    titleForTwo.title = playersForPicker[numberOfTurn]
    var lostPlayer = playersForPicker[numberOfTurn]

    titleForTwo.title = playersForPicker[numberOfTurn]

    playersForPicker.removeAtIndex(numberOfTurn)

    playerPicker.reloadAllComponents()

         playersForPicker.insert(lostPlayer, atIndex: numberOfTurn)
    startButton.setTitle("Next Turn", forState: UIControlState())
}
```

The playerPicker doesn't reload or change, So i need help on how to refresh or reload a picker view when clicking a button.

Comment: First of all, are you sure that that function is getting called? Is your `startButton` changing text like it should?

Comment: yes it is being changed

Comment: In order to be sure that your `pickerView` doesn't update its components, just put a breakpoint at the delegate / datasource methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why should it change? You are removing playersForPicker[numberOfTurn], but you set lostPlayer to that same value, then add it back to the same place in the array. The array hasn't changed, so neither will your picker. You are properly reloading your picker view. If you comment out the line where you insert lostPlayer, you should see that item disappear from the picker.